# Is there any way to further optimize Python's heapq.nlargest for selecting top N items?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, profiling, heap

I use `heapq.nlargest` to select top N items and it takes up 98% running time (**see line 51**):

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
40                                           @profile
41                                           def gen_submit(index_to_pri, index_to_sec, exclude_set, pri_mat, sec_mat, gen_count):
42         1           33     33.0      0.0      print('gen_submit')
43         1           87     87.0      0.0      f = open('../submission.txt', 'w')
44        16           28      1.8      0.0      for i, pri in enumerate(index_to_pri):
45        16          369     23.1      0.0          print('generate recommendation for %d-th primary object' % i)
46        16          103      6.4      0.0          recommend_sec = []
47        16           25      1.6      0.0          exclude = exclude_set[pri]
48        16        68215   4263.4      1.3          rating_vector = numpy.dot(pri_mat[i], sec_mat.T)
49                                                   # extract top N
50        16          102      6.4      0.0          N = 500 + len(exclude_set[pri])
51        16      4988735 311795.9     98.2          top_N_indexed_rating = heapq.nlargest(N, enumerate(rating_vector), key = lambda x: x[1]))
52        15          181     12.1      0.0          top_N_j = map(lambda x: x[0], top_N_indexed_rating)
53      7501         6229      0.8      0.1          for j in top_N_j:
54      7501         4812      0.6      0.1              if not index_to_sec[j] in exclude:
55      7500         6135      0.8      0.1                  recommend_sec.append(str(j))
56      7500         4943      0.7      0.1                  if len(recommend_sec) >= 500: break
57        15          293     19.5      0.0          f.write(' '.join(recommend_sec) + '\n')
58                                               f.close()
```

How could I further optimize this single operation?

Comment: Is it possible to build the list of N top values incrementally? It seems like largest is only efficient for small values of n.

Comment: @PaulRooney Do you mean go over the sequence 500 times (in my case)?  In addition I need to maintain a set for excluding the top k items I already found, which looks very tedious ... The worse part is that complexity turns from O(nlogk) to O(nk).

Comment: FWIW, use `with` for files; don't `close` them manually.

Comment: Do you need them to be in order? And can you give example data?

Comment: How large are `exclude` and `rating_vector` typically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### New answer

If you don't need order within `top_N_j`, try

```
top_N_j = rating_vector.argpartition(len(rating_vector) - N)[-N:]
```

Otherwise sort it afterwards with

```
top_N_j = top_N_j[numpy.argsort(rating_vector[top_N_j])]
```

I time this as taking roughly a factor of 30 to 50 less time than what you gave.

---

### Old answer

I suppose this is so obvious that I'm likely missing the point entirely, but

```
heapq.nlargest(N, enumerate(...))
```

will just take the last `N` elements, tagged by their index, in reverse order. You then only use it for

```
top_N_j = map(lambda x: x[0], top_N_indexed_rating)
```

which turns this into the index alone.

So it seems what you want is

```
end = len(...)
start = max(0, end - N)
top_N_j = reversed(range(start, end))
```

(Although I must admit to being *very* confused by what you're doing.)

Comment: Thank you for point my bug out. Actually I corrected it on my computer but didn't update my code here. Now it's updated.

Comment: What I am doing is to get the indexes of top N elements, in a word.

Comment: Good shot! Time cost of this operation has decreased from 97% to 27% with a shrinkage factor of 7.7, which is much less than you suppose, though.

Comment: Looks like partition has a lower complexity than "heap filter", which costs O(nlogk).